# How to mine in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mining-setup

How do you mine in Ubuntu 11.04? Are there any GUI miners like [poclbm-gui](https://github.com/Kiv/poclbm) for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 14):

GUIminer *can* be run on linux, although the process (described [in the official thread](http://bitcointalk.org/?topic=3878.0)) is somewhat complicated.  To summarise that post, you will need to:

1. Get the source code from [GitHub](https://github.com/Kiv/poclbm):

   `git clone https://github.com/Kiv/poclbm`
2. Install OpenCL drivers and PyOpenCL.
3. Install wxPython:

   `sudo apt-get install python-wxtools`
4. Run guiminer.py:

   `python guiminer.py`

Note that (at least to use the poclbm backend) no compiling is necessary since GUIminer is written in python.  But I can still understand if you find that process a little daunting, since I don't know your level of technological familiarity with these sorts of tasks.